# Why this UNIQUE constraint is needed?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to design schema in PostgreSQL that will contain two tables cross referencing each other. Yet if do not add redundant `UNIQUE` constrain (see code below) i am getting error: `ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "nodes"`.

So my question is: why this extra unique constraint is needed and is there a way to avoid it creation? (to reduce runtime overhead).

```
CREATE TABLE objects (
  object_id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  root_node integer
);

CREATE TABLE nodes (
   node_id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   object_id integer REFERENCES objects
);

ALTER TABLE objects
  ADD CONSTRAINT root_node_fkey
  FOREIGN KEY (root_node) REFERENCES nodes(node_id);

-- Why this constaint is needed? Since node_id is primary key this combination should be already UNIQUE
ALTER TABLE nodes ADD CONSTRAINT node_id_object_id_unique UNIQUE (node_id, object_id);

ALTER TABLE objects
  ADD CONSTRAINT objects_nodes_fkey
  FOREIGN KEY (object_id, root_node)
  REFERENCES nodes (object_id, node_id);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html says:

> **5.3.5. Foreign Keys**:
>
> . . .
>
> A foreign key must reference columns that either are a primary key or form a unique constraint. This means that the referenced columns always have an index (the one underlying the primary key or unique constraint); so checks on whether a referencing row has a match will be efficient.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/constraint_type-foreign-key-constraint/ says:

> A `FOREIGN KEY` Constraint is either a < Table Constraint> or a  and defines a rule that constrains a foreign key to values that match only those values contained in a referenced unique key.

---

Re your comment:

> The idea is that each object will have collections of nodes associated with it and only one of nodes could be the root-node.

```
ALTER TABLE objects
  ADD COLUMN root_node_id integer,
  ADD CONSTRAINT objects_nodes_fkey
  FOREIGN KEY (root_node_id)
  REFERENCES nodes (node_id);
```

That way each object references exactly one node. Admittedly, constraint doesn't strictly enforce that an object references a node that references the same object.

If you want that level of enforcement, you'll have to create the unique constraint you were asking if you had to.

Comment: Bill, is there is a way to impose similar constraint (requiring that `root_node` will be from the same `object`) in a different (possibly more efficient way)? Or this is the best way?

Comment: @Yatima, consider that you are already storing the root_node redundantly in the objects table. I mean, if you reference the object_id, then you'd be able to tell which root_node is associated with that node's object_id.

Comment: I am not sure i follow... The idea is that each object will have collections of `nodes` associated with it and only one of nodes could be the root-node. Or do you see a better way to do it? I tried to ask this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985510/what-is-best-design-for-one-to-many-relationship-with-back-references-to-each-ot but it looks to me that current scheme is the best approach so far. Btw, thank you for writing the antipaterns book - i learned a lot reading it!